Trying to limit the suggested roles while typing commands
I have been trying to reduce the amount of roles that are show while typing a slash command in a discord bot. I have some logic that I thought was correct but I must not be understanding something since it still fails to filter out roles I do not want the command to see.
Even with the whitelist it still shows all the roles in the server and not just the few I want the command to be able to see.
    // Allowed roles for the /request command (whitelist)
    const allowedRoleIds = [
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", // L⛏️ : Mining
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", // L : Hunter
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", // L : Lumberjack
    ];


    // Handle the /request command
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        
        // Check if it's an autocomplete interaction
        if (interaction.isAutocomplete()) {
            if (interaction.commandName === 'request') {
                const focusedOption = interaction.options.getFocused(true);
    
                // Only handle the "role" option
                if (focusedOption.name === 'role') {
                    try {

    
                        // Fetch and filter roles
                        const roles = interaction.guild.roles.cache.filter((role) =>
                            allowedRoleIds.includes(role.id)
                        );
    
                        // Create suggestions
                        const suggestions = roles.map((role) => ({
                            name: role.name,
                            value: role.id,
                        }));
    
                        // Respond with suggestions (limit to 25)
                        await interaction.respond(suggestions.slice(0, 25));
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error in autocomplete logic:', error);
    
                        // Ensure a fallback response to prevent unknown interaction errors
                        await interaction.respond([]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return; // Stop further processing for autocomplete interactions
        }

The issue I am seeing.

What I would prefer to be seeing.

